# Laravel friends displaying incorrectly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Ive set up a basic laravel social media website for a university project and although much of it is working, I'm having an issue with the dispalying of my friends table. I can get the friends to cycle through and display, but for some reason, it only displays the users profile page name over and over, depending on the number of friends they have in the database, I've been through the code multiple times but just cant see a reason. My code is below[image]

My Code is Below:

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */

protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = [
    'id', 'username','firstName', 'lastName', 'bio', 'DoB', 'homeLocation', 'currentLocation', 'journeys', 'friends', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];


public function getName()
{
    if ($this->firstName && $this->lastName) {
        return "{$this->firstName} {$this->lastName}";
    }

    if ($this->firstName) {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    return null;
}

public function getNameOrUsername()
{
    return $this->getName() ?: $this->username;
}

public function getFirstNameOrUsername()
{
    return $this->firstName ?: $this->username;
}

public function getAvatarUrl()
{
    return "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ md5($this->email) }}?d=mm";
}

public function statuses()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Posts', 'user_id');
}

public function friendsOfMine()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}

public function friendsOf()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'friends', 'friend_id', 'user_id');
}

public function friends()
{
    return $this->friendsOfMine()->wherePivot('accepted', true)->get()->merge($this->friendsOf()->wherePivot('accepted', true)->get());
}

public function friendRequests()
{
    return $this->friendsOfMine()->wherePivot('accepted', false)->get();
}

public function friendRequestsPending()
{
    return $this->friendsOf()->wherePivot('accepted', false)->get();
}

public function hasFriendRequestPending(User $users)
{
    return (bool) $this->friendRequestsPending()->where('id', $users->id)->count();
}

public function hasFriendRequestReceived(User $users)
{
    return (bool) $this->friendRequests()->where('id', $users->id)->count();
}

public function addFriend(User $users)
{
    $this->friendsOf()->attach($users->id);
}

public function acceptFriendRequest(User $users)
{
    $this->friendRequests()->where('id', $users->id)->first()->pivot->update([
        'accepted' => true,
    ]);
}

public function isFriendsWith(User $users)
{
    return (bool) $this->friends()->where('id', $users->id)->count();
}
}
```

ProfileController.php

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Posts;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
public function getProfile($username)
{       
    $users = User::where('username', $username)->first();

    if (!$users) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $statuses = $users->statuses()->get();

    return view('profile/index')
        ->with('users', $users)
        ->with('statuses', $statuses)
        ->with('authUserIsFriend', Auth::user()->isFriendsWith($users));
}

public function getEdit() 
{

    return view('profile/edit');

}

public function postEdit(Request $request)
{
    Auth::user()->update([
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        'firstName' => $request->input('firstName'),
        'lastName' => $request->input('lastName'),
        'bio' => $request->input('bio'),
        'DoB' => $request->input('DoB'),
        'homeLocation' => $request->input('homeLocation'),
        'currentLocation' => $request->input('currentLocation'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
    ]);

    return redirect()
        ->route('profile/edit')
        ->with('info', 'Your profile has been updated');
}
}
```

FriendController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class FriendController extends BaseController
{
public function getIndex()
{
    $friends = Auth::user()->friends();
    $requests = Auth::user()->friendRequests();

    return view('users/friends/index')
        ->with('friends', $friends)
        ->with('requests', $requests);
}

public function getAdd($username)
{
    $users = User::where('username', $username)->first();

    if (!$users) 
    {
        return redirect()->route('/home')
            ->with('info', 'That user could not be found');
    }

    if (Auth::user()->id === $users->id)
    {
        return redirect()->route('/home');
    }

    if (Auth::user()->hasFriendRequestPending($users) || $users->hasFriendRequestPending(Auth::user()))
    {
        return redirect()->route('profile/index', ['username' => $users->username])
            ->with('info', 'Friend Request Already Waiting');
    }

    if (Auth::user()->isFriendsWith($users))
    {
        return redirect()->route('profile/index', ['username' => $users->username])
            ->with('info', 'Your are already friends');
    }

    Auth::user()->addFriend($users);

    return redirect()->route('profile/index', [ 'username' => $username])
        ->with('info', 'Friend Request Sent');
}

public function getAccept($username)
{
    $users = User::where('username', $username)->first();

    if (!$users) 
    {
        return redirect()->route('/home')
            ->with('info', 'That user could not be found');
    }

    if (!Auth::user()->hasFriendRequestReceived($users))
    {
        return redirect()->route('/home');
    }

    Auth::user()->acceptFriendRequest($users);

    return redirect()->route('profile/index', ['username' => $username])
        ->with('info', 'Friend Request Accepted');
}
}
```

userblock.blade.php

```
<div class="media">
<a class="pull-left" href="{{ route('profile/index', ['username' => $users->username]) }}">
    <img class="media-object" alt="{{ $users->getNameOrUsername() }}" src="{{ $users->getAvatarUrl() }}">
</a>
<div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="{{ route('profile/index', ['username' => $users->username]) }}">{{ $users->getNameOrUsername() }}</a></h4>
</div>
@if ($users->currentLocation)
    <p>{{ $users->currentLocation }}</p>
@endif
```

users/friends/index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h3>Your Friends</h3>
        @if (!$friends->count())
            <p>Your List is Empty</p>
        @else
            @foreach ($friends as $users)
                @include('users/partials/userblock')
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h3>Requests</h3>
        @if (!$requests->count())
            <p>You Have No Requests</p>
        @else
            @foreach ($requests as $users)
                @include('users/partials/userblock')
            @endforeach
        @endif

    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: What is your question? Please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you do not know how to ask good questions.

Comment: I was asking if anyone knew why my friends list is displaying the same name over and over